# Why doesn't deleting an object of incomplete type simply cause a compilation error in C++?

Tags: c++

I can't see a good reason to not making it required for a compiler to detect this and report an error?

Is it for some backwards compatibility reason?

Are there situations where it is difficult for a compiler to detect?

Comment: More generic software engineering question dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior

Comment: Nothing at that link speaks to deleting objects of incomplete types.  I don't think a generic answer about undefined behavior in general is sufficient for this question that is specifically about a particular undefined-behavior decision.

Comment: What are you talking about? VS, icc, gcc and clang all issue a warning in this case, which you can turn into an error by supplying corresponding compilation flag.

Comment: My question is, why do you need to use some nonstandard option to do that, rather than it being an error from the outset?

Comment: `delete`-ing an object involves calling the object's destructor and passing the memory to `::operator delete()`. For a type `X` the destructor is known to be `X::~X()` and `operator delete` takes a `void*` parameter. None of this requires a complete type (at this point).

Comment: @BoPersson so... then why is it undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Bwmat - It is not undefined - unless you later declare the destructor to be virtual or provide a class specific `operator delete` override. If `struct X;` really is nothing fancy, deleting it through a pointer works well.